# Find salary difference between employee

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to find salary difference between employees.

I have a table employee.

[image: table]

My result should be

0

1000

5000

26000

How to write query?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Salary difference between which employees?

Comment: @AndrewWatson salary as ascending order and compare salary differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    emp_id,
    emp_name,
    emp_salary - COALESCE((SELECT emp_salary FROM employee e2
              WHERE e2.emp_id = e1.emp_id - 1), emp_salary) AS salary
FROM
    employee e1
ORDER BY emp_id;
```

### Demo

Another option would be to use a join:

```
SELECT
    e1.emp_id,
    e1.emp_name,
    e1.emp_salary - COALESCE(e2.emp_salary, e1.emp_salary) AS salary
FROM employee e1
LEFT JOIN employee e2
    ON e1.emp_id = e2.emp_id + 1
ORDER BY
    emp_id;
```

### Demo

Comment: is it possible to find without using sub query?

Comment: @user9006529 Yes, use a join.

Comment: @Strawberry Then I'd hate to hear your thoughts on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950767/converting-if-function-from-excel-to-sql/47950850#47950850).

Comment: I just think it undermines what SO could be, if only its users were encouraged to apply a little effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ALTER TABLE employee
      ADD dummy_emp_salary integer;
UPDATE employee SET dummy_emp_salary= 18000 where emp_id=1;
UPDATE employee SET dummy_emp_salary= 18000 where emp_id=2;
UPDATE employee SET dummy_emp_salary= 19000 where emp_id=3;
UPDATE employee SET dummy_emp_salary= 2400 where emp_id=4;

select emp_salary-dummy_emp_salary from employee;
```

Though my query is unefficient when there are millions record. Tim Biegeleisen's answer is quiet good. But if you are novice then this would be easy to understand. If you are using PL/SQL then this could be done in a much easier way.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e1.emp_name,(e1.emp_salary-e2.emp_salary) FROM `employee` e1  LEFT JOIN employee e2 ON e2.emp_id= e1.emp_id-1
```

Comment: This [won't give the desired output](http://rextester.com/MOP2183).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why?

Comment: Did you check the demo link?

Comment: ok. so my answer giving NULL value, right @TimBiegeleisen?