# Converting IF function from Excel to SQL

Tags: sql-server

A new column named "DED_LAYER_BENCHMARK_LP" is created from Excel IF function as shown below.

```
DED_LAYER_BENCHMARK_LP =  =if(_DataCell_ULFBL<=_InputCell_Deductible,

_DataCell_Original_Bench_LP_r0000_c0000,0) + 
if(_DataCell_ULFBL + _InputCell_Layer_r0000_c0000 <= _InputCell_Deductible,
    _DataCell_Original_Bench_LP_r0001_c0000, 0)
```

I want write the above excel code in SQL code

Comment: Which version you have?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN _DataCell_ULFBL <= _InputCell_Deductible
     THEN _DataCell_Original_Bench_LP_r0000_c0000
     ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN _DataCell_ULFBL + _InputCell_Layer_r0000_c0000 <= _InputCell_Deductible
     THEN _DataCell_Original_Bench_LP_r0001_c0000 ELSE 0 END AS DED_LAYER_BENCHMARK_LP
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` <s>statement</s> expression.

```
CASE 
 WHEN _DataCell_ULFBL <= _InputCell_Deductible THEN _DataCell_Original_Bench_LP_r0000_c0000 
 ELSE 0 
END + 
CASE 
 WHEN _DataCell_ULFBL + _InputCell_Layer_r0000_c0000 <= _InputCell_Deductible THEN _DataCell_Original_Bench_LP_r0001_c0000
 ELSE 0
END AS DED_LAYER_BENCHMARK_LP
```

Link to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql